# query single post with wp_query

Tags: php, html, wordpress, codex

I retrieved the latest posts in front page with WP_query loop, coz i figured out that's the best solution. but i want to display the post was clicked in front page.

what's the best method for single post query?

I used wp_query again in single.php(is there any better idea?)

```
$args =  array('name' => $the_slug,
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => 1);
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
<?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :?>

    <?php $the_query->the_post(); ?>
<p><?php $content = get_the_content('Read more');
print $content; ?></p>
<?php endwhile; ?><!-- end of the loop -->
<!-- put pagination functions here -->
    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
<?php else:  ?>

<p><?php _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' ); ?></p>

<?php endif; ?>
```

the problem is it always retrieved the latest post, even i click on any post id. how can i fix that problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't run a custom query in place of the main loop. You can simply just do the following, it is faster, more reliable and the correct way

```
<?php
            // Start the Loop.
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); 

        // YOUR LOOP ELEMENTS

    endwhile;
?>
```

**EDIT**

The above code is called the loop, the default loop to be exact. This is not a query. What this loop does, it returns only the information retrieved by the main query. The main query runs on **every page that loads**. The main query is specific for every page

For more info, read [my post on WPSE](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/155976/31545) regarding this matter

Comment: thanks, what kind of query is it? does it use wp_query or query_post? and i want to show only last 5 recent post in Home page and use pagination for that. how can i change that property?

Comment: Please see my update. Also check out the bundled themes and see how they are structured

Comment: Glad it helped :-) Enjoy

Answer (score 5):

I found the solution.

create this variable `$id= get_the_ID();`

and add `'p'=>$id to $args.`

Answer (score 0):

```
$my_query = new WP_Query( array(
  'post_type' => 'your_post_type_here',
  'p' => '$id'));// need to set the simple quote '$id'

if( $my_query->have_posts() ){
    // start the loop
}else{
    // no result message
}
```

dont forget to add simple quote to '$id' because i tried without and it was not working in my case. hope it helps someone in the future !